# VSCode: Different preferences for different Elixir extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir

*I am using the ElixirLS extension*

In my elixir project, I have files like `my_module.ex` and their corresponding test files `my_module_test.exs`, and I would like different VSCode setting for each type.

Currently in my preferences I have:

```
"[elixir]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

But I don't want to format my test files.  Is it possible to do something like this?

```
"[elixir]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
    "ignore": "*_test.exs" // Does something like this exist?
}
```

---

Alternatively, I know its possible to create a new mapping using the file associations, but couldn't find any documentation about creating a **new** type like this:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*_test.exs": "elixir_test"    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to either add or modify the `.fomatter.exs` file in your projects root folder. Behind the scenes the language server is actually using the `mix format` command to format your code. You will want something along the lines of

```
inputs: [
  "mix.exs",
  ".formatter.exs",
  "{config,lib,examples}/**/*.{ex,exs}"
],
```

I believe by default the last string includes the `test` directory. You can find more options in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Format.html) for the mix format task.

Comment: Interesting, I tried doing `inputs: [ "mix.exs" ]` but the test files are still formatted on save.  It seems like some combination of ElixirLS and VsCode are not respecting the `.formatter.exs` file.

Comment: If you run `mix format` yourself, is it doing the right thing?